# Oracle Equality that Includes Null

Tags: sql, oracle, null

Is there an Oracle equality operator that includes `NULL` values?  Or am I stuck doing a two part "(a=b) OR (a is null and b is null).

I'm trying to self join a table in Oracle

```
SELECT t1.column, t2.column FROM TABLE t1
LEFT JOIN TABLE2 t2
ON t1.foo = t2.foo
```

My query works **except** in cases where `t1` and `t2` are `null`.  And there's lots of these cases.  I can fix this with the following

```
SELECT t1.column, t2.column FROM TABLE t1
LEFT JOIN TABLE2 t2
ON ( (t1.foo = t2.foo) OR (t1.foo is null AND t2. is null) )
```

That is, I explicitly check for the double `null` case in addition to the equality case.

This makes me feel like it's 1997.  Is there a better way to do this?  A special equality operator or function that tests for nulls as well?

Comment: Has something changed since 1997 that `null` and `null` should now be equal?

Comment: @DStanley, no, but we invented null safe operators http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/comparison-operators.html#operator_equal-to

Comment: @AlanStorm, I don't understand your question. A left join that have joining columns of either left or right tables should not return result for the right part of the join.

Comment: @DStanley No, but after a few decades of programming in less strictly typed systems like we've leaned it's often useful and necessary for humans and business logic to consider things equal that the underlying system should not consider equal.

Comment: I'm unclear on what exactly is wrong with `(t1.foo = t2.foo) OR (t1.foo is null AND t2.foo is null)` - it works fine, and it's clear in its intent which is to deal with NULLs in a non-standard way. With a well-designed data model this requirement doesn't come up very often, so adding syntactical sugar for it is probably not a big priority, IMHO.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `coalesce` in your join:

```
SELECT t1.column, t2.column 
FROM TABLE t1
    LEFT JOIN TABLE2 t2
        ON coalesce(t1.foo,0) = coalesce(t2.foo,0)
```

The second value of the coalesce depends on your datatype.  Choose a value which won't already exist in the database.

Comment: This will tend to prevent the use of an index on either `foo` column, unlike the longer solution presented in the question.

Comment: Thanks sgeddes -- a useful function regardless.  And thanks @Allan for the caveat, also useful!

Comment: Even NVL would work, 

SELECT t1.column, t2.column 
FROM TABLE t1
    LEFT JOIN TABLE2 t2
        ON NVL(t1.foo,0) = NVL(t2.foo,0)

Also the problem with Coalesce is that it expects consistent data types, where NVL does an implicit conversion